# Why am I getting a "failed to create pid file...Permission Denied" error?

Tags: permissions

If a program requires write permission how should I set it with chown? Specifically, what would program foo's permissions be to solve this error?

```
failed to create pid file '/var/run/bar.pid': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a program `foo` trying to create/write to a file, the permissions of the `foo` binary don't matter, but the user *it's running as* makes all the difference.

In this case, `foo` is trying to write to `/var/run`, which is owned by `root` and *only* writable by *root*.

So you would have to run the program as `sudo foo` for it to create that PID file. Please consider the security implications of allowing a program to run as root before you do it...

Comment: if the permission on the binaries are something: rw-r-r then would the program be executable given that i am running the program as root i.e allowing to create a process id under /var/run ?

Comment: @Ankit: if a binary has no executable permissions at all it won't "run"; but anything you do run as root will be able to create a pid under `/var/run`

Comment: Alternatively, write the pid file elsewhere (many applications let you specify the path to the pid file).

Answer (score 2):

What I did is simply add the creation of a folder just before the start-stop-deamon is executed. This works because the script is generally executed as root during start up. It just creates the folder in /var/run and changes the owner immediately, so a PID can be written.

In the example below, I check for the existence of the subfolder of /var/run where i put the PIDs as the current run user, in this case user 'pi' (since I am on a raspberry).

Also check this link since it was very educational to me: [Python script to run as service](http://blog.scphillips.com/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/), however, it did not cover the problem discussed here.

Example portion of my shell script:

```
# The process ID of the script when it runs is stored here:
PIDFILE=/var/run/power/$DAEMON_NAME.pid

do_start () {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    if [ ! -d /var/run/power ]; then
        mkdir /var/run/power/
        chown pi:pi /var/run/power/
    fi
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --chdir $DIR --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    log_end_msg $?
}
```

Comment: Got a version of this for systemd?

Answer (score 1):

General approach: determine the user and group of the process trying to access the file. This is often found in the configuration of the software (such as webservers/mailservers/...), but if the software is already running use this:

```
ps aux
```

Look for the process you want to configure access rights for. The first column tells you under which username it's running.

```
groups <username>
```

This will tell you to which groups the user belongs.

Change the owner or group of the file to match the service.

Note 1: As the question points out that the file is in /var/run/ I'm assuming only one process needs access, if this is not true, you shouldn't change owner or group, but you might consider adding the process' user to the group or creating a new group for this file/folder.

Note 2: Funny things can happen with apparmor, which is a security system: it can prevent processes from writing to files and folders to which they have (on filesystem level) all necessary rights. With `aa-status` you can see whether a specific rule for your service is active.