# Permission denied (failed to create pid) when starting SphinxSearch

Tags: 14.04, permissions, services

When I try to start the SphinxSearch service like this

```
/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start
```

or this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start
```

I get the following error

```
Starting sphinxsearch: Sphinx 2.0.4-id64-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
FATAL: failed to create pid file '/var/run/sphinxsearch-searchd.pid': Permission denied
```

Here are the permissions

```
ls -ogp /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx 1 4 Apr 17  2014 /var/run -> /run/

ls -ogp /var/run/
total 52
-rw-r--r-- 1    4 May 12 05:13 acpid.pid
srw-rw-rw- 1    0 May 12 05:13 acpid.socket
drwxr-xr-x 2   60 May 18 04:27 apache2/
-rw-r--r-- 1    4 May 12 05:13 atd.pid
drwxr-xr-x 2   80 May 12 05:13 cloud-init/
-rw-r--r-- 1    4 May 12 05:13 crond.pid
---------- 1    0 May 12 05:13 crond.reboot
drwxr-xr-x 2   80 May 12 05:13 dbus/
drwxr-xr-x 2   40 May 12 05:13 initramfs/
drwxrwxrwt 3   60 May 12 10:22 lock/
-rw-r--r-- 1    5 May 12 10:23 memcached.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1    0 May 12 06:47 mlocate.daily.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1    6 May 12 10:22 monit.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1  577 May 18 03:30 motd.dynamic
drwxr-xr-x 2   60 May 12 05:13 mount/
drwxr-xr-x 2   80 May 12 06:35 mysqld/
drwxr-xr-x 3  160 May 12 05:13 network/
-rw-r--r-- 1    0 May 12 05:13 network-interface-security
-rw-r--r-- 1    5 May 12 10:22 ntpd.pid
drwxr-xr-x 2   40 May 12 05:13 plymouth/
drwxr-xr-x 2   40 May 12 05:13 pppconfig/
drwxr-xr-x 3  100 May 12 05:13 resolvconf/
-rw-r--r-- 1    4 May 12 05:13 rsyslogd.pid
drwxrwxr-x 2   40 May 12 05:13 screen/
drwxr-sr-x 5  100 May 12 10:16 sendmail/
drwxr-xr-x 2   40 May 12 05:13 sendsigs.omit.d/
drwxrwxrwt 2   40 May 12 05:13 shm/
drwxr-xr-x 2   40 May 12 07:27 sphinxsearch/
drwxr-xr-x 2   40 May 12 05:13 sshd/
-rw-r--r-- 1    4 May 12 05:13 sshd.pid
drwxr-xr-x 5  100 May 12 05:13 systemd/
drwxr-xr-x 6  160 May 12 05:13 udev/
-rw-r--r-- 1    4 May 12 05:13 upstart-file-bridge.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1    4 May 12 05:13 upstart-socket-bridge.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1    4 May 12 05:13 upstart-udev-bridge.pid
drwxr-xr-x 3   60 May 12 05:13 user/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 3456 May 18 03:30 utmp

ls -la /var/run/
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 22 root         root          780 May 18 03:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root         root         4096 May 12 05:13 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            4 May 12 05:13 acpid.pid
srw-rw-rw-  1 root         root            0 May 12 05:13 acpid.socket
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root           60 May 18 04:27 apache2
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            4 May 12 05:13 atd.pid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root           80 May 12 05:13 cloud-init
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            4 May 12 05:13 crond.pid
----------  1 root         root            0 May 12 05:13 crond.reboot
drwxr-xr-x  2 messagebus   messagebus     80 May 12 05:13 dbus
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root           40 May 12 05:13 initramfs
drwxrwxrwt  3 root         root           60 May 12 10:22 lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            5 May 12 10:23 memcached.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            0 May 12 06:47 mlocate.daily.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            6 May 12 10:22 monit.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root          577 May 18 03:30 motd.dynamic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root           60 May 12 05:13 mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql        root           80 May 12 06:35 mysqld
drwxr-xr-x  3 root         root          160 May 12 05:13 network
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            0 May 12 05:13 network-interface-security
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            5 May 12 10:22 ntpd.pid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root           40 May 12 05:13 plymouth
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root           40 May 12 05:13 pppconfig
drwxr-xr-x  3 root         root          100 May 12 05:13 resolvconf
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            4 May 12 05:13 rsyslogd.pid
drwxrwxr-x  2 root         utmp           40 May 12 05:13 screen
drwxr-sr-x  5 root         smmta         100 May 12 10:16 sendmail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root           40 May 12 05:13 sendsigs.omit.d
drwxrwxrwt  2 root         root           40 May 12 05:13 shm
drwxr-xr-x  2 sphinxsearch sphinxsearch   60 May 18 07:12 sphinxsearch
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root           40 May 12 05:13 sshd
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            4 May 12 05:13 sshd.pid
drwxr-xr-x  5 root         root          100 May 12 05:13 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  6 root         root          160 May 12 05:13 udev
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            4 May 12 05:13 upstart-file-bridge.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            4 May 12 05:13 upstart-socket-bridge.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root            4 May 12 05:13 upstart-udev-bridge.pid
drwxr-xr-x  3 root         root           60 May 12 05:13 user
-rw-rw-r--  1 root         utmp         3456 May 18 03:30 utmp
```

**Note that: 
             there was an empty a sphinxsearch dir, I changed the permissions to the sphinxsearch user and changed the PID path in sphinx, like that it is able to write a PID file, but it's supposed to be in /var/run**

Does anyone know how to solve the issue?

Comment: Try a `sudo rm /var/run/sphinxsearch-searchd.pid` and a `sudo /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch restart`

Comment: When I try to restart I get the same error as before, sphinxsearch-searchd.pid does not get created.
`rm: cannot remove '/var/run/sphinxsearch-searchd.pid': No such file or directory`

Comment: Post the output of `ls -ogp /var/run` and `ls -ogp /var/run/` –  Note the difference in the end of the commands

Comment: @FrankS. take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/174173/why-am-i-getting-a-failed-to-create-pid-file-permission-denied-error), it's may help

Comment: @FrankS. Have you noticed that OP has already tried it with `sudo`?

Comment: Replace the outpout in your question with this: `ls -la /var/run/`

Comment: Open the file `less /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch` and search for a line like `PIDFILE= …` and post the output. The line should be `PIDFILE=/var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid` and not `PIDFILE=/var/run/searchd.pid`

Comment: **PIDFILE** is set to **/var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid**

Comment: I'm not quite sure but are you using app armor? might this be related to app armor protecting /var/run? o_O Please open up two terminals. In the first you do the obvious, a tail -f /var/log/syslog and in the second you try to start the app again. Take a look if you can see smtg. which might be related an post it here. It's a shot in the dark, but AFAIRC app armor dislikes services it doesn't know, so you might have to do an audit for your application. And even if its not apparmor, syslog could show the culprit. give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

there is pidfile settings in default sphinx.conf
searchd treate this option

it looks like

```
searchd                                                                                                                                                                                  
{    
pid_file = /var/run/searchd.pid
}
```

just change it to

```
pid_file = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only write to /var/run as a user with an effective user ID of 0 (ie as root).

You should change the ownership to the user/group under which you wish to run the process.

check [this article](https://serverfault.com/questions/159334/what-permission-to-write-pid-file-in-var-run).

Comment: Have you read this? OP tried `sudo /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start`

Comment: @A.B. yes i read it, but he should change the ownership to the user/group under which he wish to run the process.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the OP change the permissions of `/var/run`?